# How to install Solr cores for Sitecore 9 on Linux

Tags: solr

I need to install the Solr cores required for Sitecore 9 on a Linux machine already running Solr 6.6.2. What is the best way to do this in Linux (since SIF cannot be used)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to installing Solr on Linux, and isn't specific to Sitecore, other than it being used by Sitecore.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. Solr is already running on Linux, just need to add the cores for Sitecore (web, fxm, marketingdefinitions etc). I'm not sure how to add these without SIF.

Comment: Okay that request sounds more like something specific to Sitecore :-)

Comment: Did the accepted answer work? I am getting the following error: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'prefix_core_index': Unable to create core [prefix_core_index] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'PATH_TO_SOLR_INSTALLATION\server\solr\prefix_core_index'

Comment: Didn't need to try it as it was decided to move to windows. The support ticket ID for this was 501654 in case you want to reference this for Sitecore support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the answer from Sitecore support, hope this helps someone: We have found the way how to create Solr cores automatically by SIF using Solr HTTP API.

In order to perform this, you should delete all children of the Tasks node of the "xconnect-solr.json" file and create tasks for creating Solr cores which should look in the following way:

```
"CreateXDBSolrCore":{
        "Type": "ManageSolrCore",
        "Params": {
            "Action": "Create",
            "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]",
            "Arguments": {
                "name" : "[variable('Xdb.Name')]",
                "instanceDir": "[variable('Xdb.Name')]",
                "configSet": "basic_configs"
            }
        }
    },
"CreateXDBRebuildSolrCore":{
        "Type": "ManageSolrCore",
        "Params": {
            "Action": "Create",
            "Address": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]",
            "Arguments": {
                "name" : "[variable('Xdb.Rebuild.Name')]",
                "instanceDir": "[variable('Xdb.Rebuild.Name')]",
                "configSet": "basic_configs"
            }
        }
    }
```

The similar operation should be performed for the "sitecore-solr.json" file, but you should create the different set of cores. You can get all needed Solr core names from the "sitecore-solr.json " file.

Answer (score 1):

I would take Kam Figys Solr script
https://gist.github.com/kamsar/ef8811bd458603f1e808
and take the relevant parts out of it (remove the actual installation).
You might need to upload the schema.xml yourself